# How to evaluate this integral $\int \frac{dx}{16+5^{2-3x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the following integral
$$\int \frac{dx}{16+5^{2-3x}}=?$$

My attempt:

Assume that $2-3x=t$, $-3dx=dt$, $dx=-\frac{dt}{3}$
$$\int \frac{-dt/3}{16+5^{t}}=-\frac13\int \frac{dt}{16+5^{t}}$$
let $ 5^t=u$, $\implies 5^t\ln 5\ dt=du$, $dt=\frac{du}{u\ln 5}$
$$-\frac13\int \frac{\frac{du}{u\ln 5}}{16+u}$$
$$=-\frac1{3\ln 5}\int \frac{du}{u(16+u)}$$
$$=-\frac1{3\ln 5}\int \frac{1}{16}(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{16+u})du$$
$$=-\frac1{48\ln 5}(\ln u-\ln(u+16))$$
I back substituted, $u=5^t$
$$=-\frac1{48\ln 5}(\ln 5^t-\ln(5^t+16))$$

I again back substituted, $t=2-3x$
$$=-\frac1{48\ln 5}(\ln 5^{2-3x}-\ln(5^{2-3x}+16))$$
after simplification i got the answer
$$=\frac1{48\ln 5}\ln\left(\frac{16+5^{2-3x}}{5^{2-3x}}\right)+c$$
In this integral I used two succesive substitutions, which is a bit lengthier. Can the same integral be calculated by some easier method? Can I evaluate by a single substitution? some body please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be written as
$$I=\int \frac{5^{3x}dx}{16.5^{3x}+25}$$
with $5^{3x}=e^{3x\ln(5)}$,

The derivative of the denominator is
$$16.3.\ln(5).e^{3x\ln(5)}=48\ln(5)5^{3x}$$

thus

$$I=\frac{1}{48\ln(5)}\ln(16.5^{3x}+25)+C$$

Comment: how did you find derivative of denominator $48\ln(5)5^{3x}$? can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @Jyerkimenon You use the exponential.

Comment: so you solved without substitution?

Comment: @Jyerkimenon I just used the fact that the antiderivative of $u'/u$ is $\ln(|u|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use single substitution

Let $16+5^{2-3x}=t\implies 5^{2-3x}\ln 5\cdot (-3)=dt$, $dx=\frac{dt}{3(16-t)\ln 5}$
$$\int \frac{dx}{16+5^{2-3x}}=\int \frac{1}{t}\frac{dt}{3(16-t)\ln 5}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3\ln5}\int \frac{dt}{t(16-t)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3\ln5}\frac{1}{16}\int\left( \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t-16}\right)\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{48\ln5}\int \left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t-16}\right)\ dt$$

Answer (score 0):

It saves a substitution if you do this...

$\int \frac {dx}{16 + 5^{2-3x}}\ dx\\
\int \frac {dx}{16 + 25 (5^{-3x})}\ dx\\
\int \frac {dx}{16 + 25 e^{-3x\ln 5}}\ dx$

Now our substitution $u = e^{-3x\ln 5}, du = e^{-3x\ln 5}(-3\ln 5)\ dx, dx = -\frac {1}{3\ln 5 u}\ du$

$-\frac {1}{3\ln 5}\int \frac {1}{u(16 + 25u)} \ du$

And proceed with the partial fractions as above.